# How to use dynamic operator in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

In one of my function, i have to use either + or - as an operator according to conditions.

for  example,

```
$a = 10;
$b = 20;
if($status==true){
  $operator = "+";
}else{
  $operator = "-";
}

$calculate = $a.$operator.$b;

return $calculate;
```

Problem is, it gives output concatenating operator like "10+20" instead of giving actual calculations

Comment: You're overengineering this. Just do the calculation in the `if-else`.

Comment: @El_Vanja this is just an example ...actually my code is very big and i don't want code to be redundant

Comment: Using the same operands in *different* calculation formulas can hardly qualify as redundancy. I'd still call this overengineering.

Comment: Another way : `$res = $a + $b * ($status ? 1 : -1)`.

Comment: `$calc = ($status) ? $a+$b : $a-$b;` If you want to avoid redundancy extract bigger parts like advanced calculation to functions/methods. (*republished comment for fixing typos*)

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is my version to *dynamic operator*

```
public function operator($a, $b, $operator): int
{
    if($operator === '+'){
        return $a + $b;
    } elseif($operator === '-'){
        return $a - $b;
    } elseif($operator === '*'){
        return $a * $b;
    }elseif($operator === '/'){
        return $a / $b;
    }
    return $a % $b; // In case you need Modulus
}

$test = operator(10, 20, '+');
echo $test; // 30

if($status){
   operator($a, $b, '+'); // From your Example
} else {
   operator($a, $b, '-');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the code below, in your code the server get operator as a string not as an operator:

```
$a = 10;
$b = 20;
$calculate = "";
if ($status == true) {
    $calculate = $a + $b;
} else {
    $calculate = $a - $b;
}

return $calculate;
```